# how to create channel websocket in node js server

Tags: node.js, websocket, channel

I want to create a channel in a websocket server using node js and to send message to the subscribers.
I need a simple code to start.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Google 'node websockets' and 'socket.io'. There are plenty of resources that'll teach you how to do this, if you do a little research of your own.

Comment: I found many examples of creating  a server node js but  not how to create a channel. I'm working with node js and javascript for the first time.

Answer (score 5):

Using [socket.io](http://socket.io/), you can easily create channels to differentiate subscribers to different groups. Socket.io calls the channels `Rooms` and you can [read the documentation for details](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#rooms).

In essence, when clients connect to the socket, you have them join a specific room:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

Whenever you emit an event (sending messages in your case), you can send it to clients in that room:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```